# Redirect to a new tab within javascript file

Tags: javascript, popup, anchor

I have code that sets:

```
top.location.href = [someurl]
```

But I want it to open up in a new tab. Is there anyway to have the above code include: `target="_blank"`?

Answer (score 106):

Use the method `window.open(url, target)` to open a new window (it depends on the browser or the user's settings whether the URL is opened in a new window or tab):

```
window.open('http://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
```

For more information about `window.open()`, read the [documentation at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Please note: Randomly opening a new window (or tab) isn't allowed in most browsers, because it is then treated as an "unwanted popup".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry, you're absolutely right. Already changed the link.

Comment: _blank isn't necessarily required since it is the default.

Answer (score 20):

**If** you're doing this in response to a user's action (such as a click), you can use `window.open`:

```
window.open("someurl", "_blank");
```

On most browsers with default settings, that will open a new tab rather than a new window. The user is, of course, in charge and can change the settings so it's a new window instead.

You cannot do this with a decent browser if it's not in response to a user's click, so that web pages cannot open tabs randomly.

Answer (score 7):

Here is alternative for window.open - working [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/krfncLwx/) (stackoverflow snippets not allow to opening)

```
let a= document.createElement('a');
a.target= '_blank';
a.href= 'https://example.com/';
a.click();
```

Answer (score -4):

Use this code

```
 window.open ('URL', "_newtab" );
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that the other ones here have not?

Comment: Can expand your answer, and link to some source about `_newtab` please

Comment: <script> window.open ('https://facebook.com', "_newtab" ); </script> 

Add the above code in a file , and run it on browser.

Comment: The question is : what's the added value of using **_newtab** rather than **_blank** ? You just paste a JS line with no explanation. Stackoverflow desserve a better answer ! Thanks.